# Questions which are clear enough, yet rejected!

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have asked several questions in Physics. I never seem to get a satisfactory answer. The only people who do answer are those who are overly concerned about form and structure of the question but does not have anything at all to contribute to the answer of the question.

Is this site about "how to ask questions?" or is it about asking physics questions to get either mathematical solutions or appropriate answers to the "physics" questions?

Comment: Currently only [1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341873/2451) of your [7](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/27597/vick?tab=questions&sort=newest) questions is closed. Are you asking why it is closed & how to reopen it?

Comment: No I am asking about the other questions for which I am forced to either rephrase, edit, add or remove things in my questions.

Comment: I think my complaint is clear enough in English! If there is ambiguity, it is certainly not in my questions!!

Comment: You write that you _never seem to get a satisfactory answer,_ yet 6 of your 7 questions has an answer, and 4 of your 7 questions has an accepted answer. General tip: _If an answer is not satisfactory, don't accept it._

Comment: The only really satisfactory answer I accepted was for the question: "What are the general relativity equations for relativistic constant acceleration?". And for this question, it was you who asked that the question be edited!

Comment: Whereas the other questions, for want of better answers, I accepted them nonetheless.

Comment: @Vick By accepting the answer, you are saying "This provides an acceptable answer to my question that I am satisfied with."  It's not fair for you to then come here and complain that your questions are not producing the quality of answers you would like.  It is **your responsibility** to accept answers that **you** feel answer **your** questions.  You cannot blame the community for that, it is you _telling_ the community that those answers are good.

Comment: Ok henceforth I will accept answers that are really good. Sorry about previously accepting answers even though they lack precision and depth.

Comment: Vick, that's an interesting approach you have so I have to ask *what is your intention*?  If it is to diminish yourself in the eyes of most of this community, then I think your approach is promising.  If it is to find out how to get more volunteers here interested in answering your questions to your satisfaction then...  maybe a rethink is in order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People who post questions on this site are not entitled to answers which satisfy them. They are not entitled to any answers at all. Answers are provided free of charge by users who donate their time, effort and (hopefully) their expertise. They have no obligation to answer even if they have that expertise.

The more advanced or specialised the topic, the fewer users who will feel able to answer. Your questions are moderately advanced, so you should not expect to get many answers.

If you are not satisfied with the answers provided, the onus is on you to explain why. I can see only 1 comment by you among the 4 answers which you have accepted, and that comment (in [How to induce artificial gravity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/317225)) was answered.

I can see only one comment to which you have not received a response, on the question [Friedmann equations for an open and accelerating expansion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/285596).

Besides providing feedback on answers, you can also increase the exposure of your question (and the chances of getting more and better answers) by editing it to make it clearer or to provide additional context. This additional information should appear in the question rather than in comments, as recommended in the comments to your latest question [Anisotropy and the Planck results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/341873). [Editing the question bumps it to the top of the homepage](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers), giving it more exposure. Comments do not do this, and are easily overlooked.

Older questions tend to be neglected. In many cases the asker has lost interest so answers are less likely to be accepted or to get upvotes. So users looking for questions to answer concentrate on those with recent activity. If you still want answers, you have to keep the question "live" by editing it.

And as others point out, accepting an answer indicates that you are satisfied with it and do not need other answers.

Users who provide suggestions about the form and content of your questions are trying to be helpful. They might not be able to answer your questions, but they can give useful feedback which will make your question more attractive to those who can provide answers.

Answer (score 10):

Of the seven questions you have asked five of them have been answered with no or only minor edits to the question.

The question [Cosmology parameters](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278003/cosmology-parameters) was edited because it contained multiple different questions and we require only one question per post. The question was edited and subsequently answered, and you have accepted the answer. In fact four of the questions have answers that you have accepted and [one more](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285596/friedmann-equations-for-an-open-and-accelerating-expansion) has an answer that seems pretty good to me but which you haven't accepted for some reason.

There is just the one question [Anisotropy and the Planck results](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/341873/anisotropy-and-the-planck-results) that is on hold pending clarification.

So the evidence does not support your claim that:

> I never seem to get a satisfactory answer. The only people who do answer are those who are overly concerned about form and structure of the question but does not have anything at all to contribute to the answer of the question.

Comment: I suspect OP is discussing the closed question, which was closed *after* the relevant passage I'd recommended adding was added.

Comment: Ok. I have looked at my questions closely. And the answers as I stated above are not really satisfactory but nonetheless I accepted some of them. Basically I maintain my claim, that the number of people looking at the questions to answer them from a science perspective are few and those that are answering are not providing really good answers. Except of course for the one I mentioned above: "What are the general relativity equations for relativistic constant acceleration?"

Comment: But most of the people who are getting involved with the question are those that are concerned with form and structure of the question.

Comment: @John Rennie: The answers are not satisfactory! There may be 1 or 2 persons who have cared to actually answer the questions! But the number of people on the Edit list is 4 or 5.

Comment: For example: I ask a simple question: "What is your age?" It should be fairly simple to answer. But you guys wants me to clarify the question and specify whether age is in number of hours, days or years? And the question is being asked by who? , etc

Comment: Ok guys I get it! You guys are earning reputation and votes by making edits and so forth? Isn't it?

Comment: @Vick Sometimes, someone may not actually know _the answer_; but they know enough to suggest ways to make the question better suited to the site.  In doing so, they are increasing the probability that someone who _does_ know the answer will be able _and willing_ to assist.  If the question requires too many changes to fit with the site policies; it either isn't good for this site, or perhaps needs to be formulated differently or broken into more questions.  You need to _stop accepting answers_ if they are not adequate.  You are discouraging better answers by marking inadequate answers accepted

Comment: @JMac ok I understand your point! But have you taken a look at my last question? How can I formulate it differently? How can it be more concise or clearer than it already is? A person who is familiar with the contents of the question will have no difficulty in making a reply. I've even provided a link to the ESA article for background. I just don't understand how am I supposed to make it any clearer or to comply with the site policies.

Comment: It is really 1 question but several components are inter-related that I have to mention them with regard to the question. For example if I asked how old you are and then on which week day were you born? I cannot ask on which week day on its own as it will give me no clue as to what date. Both of these must be asked together.

Comment: @Vick A question is closed after multiple senior users vote to close it.  Ergo the question is unclear to *multiple* users, irrespective of how clear it is in the mind of the OP.

Answer (score 7):

This has already shown up in the comments, but seems worth promoting to an answer.
You say, in questions and comments,

> I never seem to get a satisfactory answer. ... Whereas the other questions, for want of better answers, I accepted them nonetheless.

This is a case of "Doc, it hurts when I do this" being answered with "Well, don't don't do that."  Accepting an answer is how you announce to the world that you find it satisfactory.  On-topic questions here can accept new answers basically for ever --- there are even badges awarded for bringing an old question [back](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/59/revival) from the [dead](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/necromancer).  But someone who is trawling through the back catalogue of questions is unlikely to go to the effort of writing a *new* answer to your question if you've already got an answer marked as "acceptable."